# How is fructose absorbed into the body

Tags: human-physiology, digestion

I’m finding contradicting methods of   Fructose  transfer to blood

[page no 264(10)](http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/kebo116.pdf)One of which saYs fructose is absorbed by simple diffusion

And another sources like [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4817407/) say that fructose is absorbed by facilitated diffusion

I Believe that second source is true but still which one is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fructose is absorbed by **facilitated diffusion** in the small intestine by the help of transport molecules GLUT5 or GLUT2.

Sources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fructose
- http://diabetes.diabetesjournals.org/content/54/10/3056.long

The source you've mentioned (http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/kebo116.pdf), says that certain monosaccharides, such as glucose, can be absorbed by simple diffusion, but it says nothing specifically about fructose.

In fructose malabsorption, in which the transporter GLUT5 is deficient, fructose absorption can be very decreased, which suggests there is probably no additional absorption of fructose by simple diffusion ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3934501/)).